# OOP classes: Override static method in child class, depending of called method

Tags: class, oop, inheritance, overriding, static-methods

I have the ParentClass, with method TestMethod (**NOTE: I shouldn't make any changes to the ParentClass at all, it should stay as it is**):

```
class ParentClass{ 
    public static function TestMethod() { 
        return "original method"; 
    } 
}
```

And the child class that extends original class has two additional methods (ChildMethod1 and ChildMethod2) that are not included in the ParentClass:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{ 

    public function ChildMethod1() { 
        .
        .
        . 
    } 
    public function ChildMethod2() { 
        .
        .
        .
    } 

}
```

I'm instancing and working with an objects from ChildClass. But I need to override the TestMethod from the ParentClass.

In the moment when I will call the ChildMethod1, the TestMethod from the ParentClass should be overriden and to look like this:

```
public static function TestMethod() { 
    return "child method 1"; 
}
```

and in the moment when I will call the ChildMethod2, the TestMethod should be overridden like this:

```
public static function TestMethod() { 
    return "child method 2"; 
}
```

so probably the ChildClass should look like this:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{ 

    public function ChildMethod1() { 
        .
        .
        . 
    } 
    public function ChildMethod2() { 
        .
        .
        .
    } 

    public function TestMethod() {
        if(some condition){
             return "child method 1"; 
        } else {
             return "child method 2"; 
        }
    }

}
```

NOTE: TestMethod in ParentClass is actually a static function.

Is there any way of implementing this logic without any change to the ParentClass? I was thinking maybe introducing the variable in ChildClass can help us in the creating the conditions in overriden class, but not sure how to implement all of that.

Comment: Static methods are never overridden.  They can be shadowed by using an identical name in a subclass (bad practice), but a static method can always be invoked with a fully qualified member name, eg. `ParentClass.testMethod()`.  If you need to override `testMethod()` in a subclass, then you should refactor your object model so that the method becomes an instance method of `ParentClass`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, since a static method isn't part of a class instance, it can't be overridden. This is by design in every programming language in the world.

### If these *static methods* were *instance methods*...

...probably you would end up implementing two derived class of `ParentClass` and that conditional logic would be implemented where you instantiate the so-called *derived classes*, and this means that you would be taking advantage of *polymorphism*:

```
ParentClass instance;

if([condition])
{
    instance = new DerivedClass1();
}
else
{
    instance = new DerivedClass2();
}

    instance.OverriddenMethod();
}
```

When you cast a reference of a most derived instance into a less derived one, you're performing an *upcast*. While you're *upcasting* either `DerivedClass1` or `DerivedClass2`, you're not losing their implementations of `OverriddenMethod`, because *upcasting* just reduces the typing without losing implementation details.